# Anchor links not working in IE11

Tags: html, hyperlink, navigation, anchor, navbar

I've been searching on here for a solution for the past few days, and despite finding a couple of related articles, unfortunately they were for older version of IE & hence the fixes didn't work :(

On this site http://zenyx.com/ the navigation links have been setup to use section IDs. They work perfectly on Chrome & Firefox but only seem to work on IE11 if the page is manually refreshed after the link has been clicked. Is there any way to fix this so that a manual refresh isn't required for the links to work properly in IE11?

Cheers

Comment: Hi, please check out http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask

Comment: What happens if you remove `name="section-front-page"` or `id="section-front-page"` since you have both

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need this answered but for anyone else having this issue with IE 11 here is the fix that worked for me.

I had a button at the top of the page to link to a giving form further down.

```
<button><a href="#giving-form">Give Now</a></button>

<div id="giving-form">{{insert form here}}</div>
```

however it didn't work in IE 11. The reason is that the button element blocks the click event from triggering the  tag. So easy fix it to wrap your button element inside of your a tag.

```
<a href="#giving-form"><button>Give Now</button></a>

<div id="giving-form">{{insert form here}}</div>
```